# Purpose of RecyclerView.NO_POSITION and smoothScrollToPosition()?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I’m some kind of new working with `RecyclerView` and I have noticed lately on one of the tutorials that they use `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` with `smoothScrollToPosition()`.

Here's the example:

```
 private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 private int mPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

 @Override                                                                                             
 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (mPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) mPosition = 0;
    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mPosition);
}
```

But I don’t know exactly what `NO_POSITION` or this `smoothScrollToPosition()` actually do? Also I tried to search official doc, other essays or checking other guys questions here. Unfortunately, none helped me.

Can anyone explain what their purpose/why do we need to use them?

Comment: Weird. When I google `no_position` I get this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition() and when I google `smoothScrollToPosition` I find this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#smoothscrolltoposition

Comment: I said i searched official documentation but wasn't able to get it, So I'm questioning here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO_POSITION is a constant whose value is -1, it basically means that when don't you find the position of the model in the underlying dataset the return value of this method will be NO_POSITION.

smoothScrollToPostion(value) tells your view to go to that particular position in the recyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

NO_POSITION is an int with -1 value;

smoothScrollToPosition() will scroll the RecyclerView to the requested position.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API docs:

`RecyclerView.NO_POSITION` is a constant value -1.

And in case of `getBindingAdapterPosition()` method `NO_POSITION` is used for when item has been removed from the `adapter`, `RecyclerView` and/or `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` has been called after the last layout pass or the `ViewHolder` has already been recycled.

`smoothScrollToPosition` starts a smooth scroll to an adapter position. If the adapter position is  `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`, then it means something went wrong, and it might even throw an exception in your code, so be careful!